# how do i merge these two select statements?

Tags: mysql

i have 2 select statements, 1 for getting the latest failed status and one for getting the latest missed status. in the 3rd i need to have a statement if the latest status is with missed or failed but it seems to have merged the data? im using LIKE because the missed and failed may vary slightly

```
mysql> select max(scheduled_start),node_name,schedule_name,status from `events_server` WHERE status LIKE '%Failed%'and node_name='name';
+----------------------+----------------+---------------+-----------+
| max(scheduled_start) | node_name      | schedule_name | status    |
+----------------------+----------------+---------------+-----------+
| 2013-01-30 15:00:00  | name           | name_1500     | Failed  1 |
+----------------------+----------------+---------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select max(scheduled_start),node_name,schedule_name,status from `events_server` WHERE status LIKE '%Missed%'and node_name='name';
+----------------------+----------------+---------------+--------+
| max(scheduled_start) | node_name      | schedule_name | status |
+----------------------+----------------+---------------+--------+
| 2013-01-23 08:00:00  | name           | NAME_0800     | Missed |
+----------------------+----------------+---------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select max(scheduled_start),node_name,schedule_name,status from `events_server` WHERE (status LIKE '%Failed%' OR status LIKE '%Missed%') and node_na
me='name';
+----------------------+----------------+---------------+--------+
| max(scheduled_start) | node_name      | schedule_name | status |
+----------------------+----------------+---------------+--------+
| 2013-01-30 15:00:00  | name           | NAME_0800     | Missed |
+----------------------+----------------+---------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something similar to this which will *pivot* the data and return a separate column for each status. This will give you the `max(scheduled_start)` for both the `Failed` and `Missed` statuses. But you also need to add a `GROUP BY` to get the result:

```
select 
    max(case when status LIKE '%Failed%' then scheduled_start end) Failed,
    max(case when status LIKE '%Missed%' then scheduled_start end) Missed,
    node_name,
    schedule_name
from `events_server`
where node_name='name'
 AND (status LIKE '%Missed%' OR status LIKE '%Failed%')
group by node_name, schedule_name
```

Comment: thanks very much! i was trying to get just one row, which if i "order by failed" using your statement i can get by using PHP to select the last row. your way make much more sense :)